# Lost update solution

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I want to solve lost update problem in my application, the problem when between read and update of one transaction another transaction do the update.

What I want to know is if I can solve it just by putting certain isolation level in SQL Server (READ_COMMITTED, READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or SNAPSHOT), or I must implement the logic in the application layer, like add row version field to my Entity classes, and manually check it and do rollbacks when it occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `READ_COMMITTED` and `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` doesn't support `Update conflict detection`, only `SNAPSHOT` supports it. Source: [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050(v=sql.105).aspx).

So to resolve lost updates in DB layer `SNAPSHOT` isolation level must be used.

If `READ_COMMITTED` or `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is used, then Lost update problem must be solved in application layer. Here is how it is done [Row versioning in Entity framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 1):

This is nice article explaining Lost updates problem - https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/ 
It suggests REPEATABLE-READ isolation level and it actually works (in this case in Postgres).

But for example, in mysql repeatable-read doesn't solve lost updates and you have to use some kind of locking for example `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0):

To prevent lost updates transactions must be run at an isolation level of at least repeatable read, combined with a transaction block in the application layer.

Comment: I want optimistic locking, not pessimistic.

Comment: If you target is to improve concurrency and not lock data during a read operation, then you can take advantage of Read Committed Snapshot Isolation.
You can enable RCSI by altering database or you run snapshot isolation transaction on specific tables.

Altering database:

ALTER DATABASE dbName SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
BEGIN TRAN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE